# Windows sound was not working

Tags: windows-10, administrator, system-sounds

I try to recover laptop, that has on issue over playing sound, i'll check with all services in `services.msc` that related to audio, but  everything was running. but not have any sound while playing video. And another odd one is `Run as administrator` was not show in search window but i currently login as administrator. And also `sfc /scannow` but that not able to solve problem. How can i sort it out

---

Audio driver working, And i'm able to raise and reduce volume. But sound was not working, Even i'll check with audio jack but not working. Update drive with driver pack solution that ends up with installation error

Comment: Are the drivers related to audio working properly?

Comment: Do you have a speaker icon in the bottom right? If so, click it and see if the right audio device is selected, Click it and see if you can change it? It may be that there is a second audio device and that it is set to the selected audio device, but with no connectors attached. for example headphones vs speakers. (common issue on laptops)

Comment: Audio driver working, And i'm able to raise and reduce volume. But sound was not working, Even i'll check with audio jack but not working. Update drive with driver pack solution that ends up with installation error